# CCSpriteBatchNode not being retained?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, exc-bad-access

I have an app that uses sprite sheets and is a Cocos2D/UIKit app. In the init method of my scene I do this:

```
spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"TheSpriteSheet.pvr.ccz"];
[self addChild:spriteSheet z:1];
```

Now when the game is over, I do this:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] actionManager] removeAllActions];
[self unscheduleAllSelectors];
```

This causes the CCSprites that are currently still as a child to remain there so once I finish my UIKit view transition to my other `UIViewController` I try to call a method back in my `CCLayer` class (the class the scene is in) to remove all the children that were in my `CCSpriteBatchNode`, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Now I HAVE to call the method at this point because I want to achieve the effect of the enemies still being on screen while I am doing my custom view transition so they don't magically disappear before I finish switching views. Also I do not do replaceScene anywhere or release my batch node explicitly so I don't know why this is happening.

Anyway how would I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you call stopAnimation instead? This should freeze the scene, and you should be able to transition it with UIKit. In any case, it seems rather odd that removing all actions and unscheduling would cause some nodes to dealloc. May point to an over-release somewhere, if you're not using ARC.

Comment: I also have this bit of code that I call too: [spriteSheet removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:NO]; Would that cause the spriteSheet to get released?

Comment: Would you like to see the code that I do to remove the sprites from the batch node after I transition views?